# mysql query wrong results on group

Tags: mysql

I am creating a simple forum app for website and here is my table schema...

Here is mysql query to get all categories, total_topics, total_posts, and last_topic_date...

```
SELECT fc.id, fc.name, fc.var_name, fc.description, fc.dnt, COUNT(ft.id) AS total_topics, COUNT(fp.id) AS total_posts, MAX(ft.dnt) AS last_topic_date 
FROM forum_categories fc
LEFT JOIN forum_topics ft ON ft.category_id = fc.id
LEFT JOIN forum_posts fp ON fp.topic_id = ft.id
GROUP BY fc.id
```

[mysql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad2a6/2/0)

As you can see i am getting 3 total_topic while there is only 2 topics available in that category. Please help me to fix this. thanks.

Comment: Props for giving a formatted query and a sql fiddle.. +1

Comment: this is how everyone should build questions... easy to read and solve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the solved answer here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad2a6/3

```
SELECT 
    fc.id, 
    fc.name, 
    fc.var_name, 
    fc.description, 
    fc.dnt, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ft.id) AS total_topics, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT fp.id) AS total_posts, 
    MAX(ft.dnt) AS last_topic_date -- oldest date for most recent use MIN(ft.dnt) AS last_topic_date 
FROM forum_categories fc
LEFT JOIN forum_topics ft ON ft.category_id = fc.id
LEFT JOIN forum_posts fp ON fp.topic_id = ft.id
GROUP BY fc.id
```

when you left join you aren't filtering out null records so you have to clarify DISTINCT in your count to get the correct COUNT(). INNER JOINS are generally faster and could be a better solution unless you dont want filtering.

Comment: thanks for your help, please even suggest if my approach is correct to get 'last_topic_date'

Comment: if you are trying to get the most recent date then use MIN(). if you want the last date then use MAX() because MAX will return the oldest date